# how to make the vAxis and hAxis number in integer

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Here is my code:

```
 var rawdata='".$performances."';
            var mydata=jQuery.parseJSON(rawdata);
            if(mydata){
                var realData=[];
                realData=[
                      ['Activities', 'Performance'],
                    ];

            for (x in mydata)
            {
                var a=parseFloat(mydata[x]['activities']);
                var b=parseFloat(mydata[x]['performance']);
                realData[x]=[a,b];
            }
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(realData);
            var options = {
              title: 'Overall Performance',
              legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
              hAxis: {title: 'Activities'},
              vAxis: {title: 'Performance'} 
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_line'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
```

And the output is:

[image]

I want to change the current x axis value to be integer: 1,2,3,4,...., how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `var a = parseInt(mydata[x]['activities']);` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different approaches you can take to fix this.  The first is to set the axis range and gridline count so that the chart defaults to showing integer values, eg:

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 2
    },
    gridlines: {
        count: 3
    }
}
```

Generally, if `min` and `max` are integers and `(max - min) / (count - 1)` is an integer, then the gridlines (and hence axis labels) will fall on integer values.  This approach works best with the y-axis when you know the range of valid values for your chart; you can use it for the x-axis too, but I don't see it used very often.

The other approach is to use the `h/vAxis.ticks` option to specify the locations of gridlines and labels.  The `ticks` option takes an array of values or objects.  Values specify the location of a gridline.  Objects have `v` and `f` properties; the `v` property specifies the location of the gridline and the `f` property specifies the label to use.  Any values or objects without a specified `f` property will generate an axis label according to the axis `format` option.

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

or:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: 1, f: 'one'}, {v: 2, f: 'two'}, {v: 3, f: 'three'}, {v: 4, f: 'four'}]
}
```

You can mix and match objects and values in the array however you like.  This approach works equally well with both the x and y axes.

You can take one approach with one axis and the other approach with the other axis, but if you mix them on the same axis, be aware that the `ticks` option overrides `gridlines.count`, and if you place a tick mark outside the range of the `viewWindow` settings, you will not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var a=parseFloat(mydata[x]['activities'].toFixed());
var b=parseFloat(mydata[x]['performance'].toFixed());
```

`toFixed()` will convert your number to a string; you are using `parseFloat()`, so the string would be converted back to a number.

Comment: it does not work and this is not I want. I want to change the numbers in x-axis line.